# Add different class name to images based on their layout orientation with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to use plain javascript to apply either the class name `portrait` or `landscape` to all `<img>` elements with a certain class name based on whether the image file itself is taller than it is wide (portrait orientation) or wider than it is tall (landscape orientation).

I know I can get all of the elements by class name like so:

`var portalPics = document.getElementsByClassName("portal-pic");`

And I think I can tell the orientation of each image file by comparing the `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` properties of [the HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone help me write the script that I would insert before the closing `</body>` tag in my HTML document that would automatically add the desired class names to the desired images?

Comment: You're going to have better luck searching the web for a solution. SA is going to help you solve specific problems or hangups you run into. Don't ask a question expecting users to write a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop, check, and assign:

```
var portalPics = document.getElementsByClassName("portal-pic");
for (var i = 0; i < portalPics.length; i++) {
    if (portalPics[i].naturalWidth > portalPics[i].naturalHeight) {
        portalPics[i].className += " landscape";
    } else {
        portalPics[i].className += " portrait";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, however, a blank space character is needed before the class names "landscape" and "portrait" (ie: " landscape" and " portrait") in order to actually work (else the new class names are just concatenated to the end of the class name "portal-pic". Thanks tymeJV for helping me with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

if you compare image width with height, then you know which class to add:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
var images = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
images.forEach(function(img) {
  if (img.width > img.height) {
    img.className += img.className ? ' landscape' : 'landscape';
  }
  else {
    img.className += img.className ? ' portrait' : 'portrait';
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been upvoted twice, it definitely doesn't work. `.forEach()` method doesn't work on `nodeList`. Also there's a syntax error within the code: It should be like `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg]);`.

Comment: You are too particular in my opinion ;)

Comment: It's not about me and/or you :-) the *code* is the object. Anyway, I withdraw my down-vote as you've already updated the answer.

Comment: Thx Hashem. I have created the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mcceuj6/3/) as a working sample.